# Does $g(s) = a_1 \exp( - \frac{c_1}{2s^2} )+ a_2 \exp(-\frac{c_2}{2s^2})$ have an inflection point on $(0,\infty)$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let $a_1,a_2,c_1,c_2$ be strictly positive real numbers.

Consider the following function on $0 < s < \infty$
$$
g(s) = a_1 \exp( - \frac{c_1}{2s^2} )+ a_2 \exp(-\frac{c_2}{2s^2}).
$$

Does $g$ have an inflection point? A definition can be found here https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Point_of_inflection  .

I can prove the existence of an $s_0$ such that $g^{''}(s_0) = 0$ but I cannot prove it is an inflection point.

My work so far:

$h(s) := g'(s)$ has the following properties: 
$h(s) > 0$ for all $s > 0$ and $\lim_{s\to\infty} h(s) = 0.$ Also $h'(s) > 0$ for all sufficiently small $s$ and $h'(s) < 0$ for all sufficiently large $s.$

This means we can find $0 < s_1 < s_2$ such that $h(s_1) < h(s_2)$ while $h^{'}(s_1) > 0$ and $h^{'}(s_2) < 0$. Let $s_0 = \sup \{ s \in [s_1,s_2] : h'(s) > 0 \text{ for all } s \in [s_1,s] \}.$ It is easy to see that $s_1 < s_0 < s_2$, $h^{'}(s_0) = 0$, and $h'(s) > 0$ on $[s_1,s_0)$. This shows $g$ is convex on $[s_1,s_0)$.
If I could prove there is a $\epsilon >0$ such that $h^{'}(s) < 0$ on $(s_0,s_0+\epsilon)$ then $g$ would be concave on $(s_0,s_0 + \epsilon)$  and the proof would be complete. But I am stuck here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let
$$
g(s) = a_1 \exp( - \frac{c_1}{2s^2} )+ a_2 \exp(-\frac{c_2}{2s^2}).
$$
where $a_1,a_2,c_1,c_2$ are strictly positive.

We will show that $g(s)$ has an inflection point in $(0,\infty)$ in the following sense : there is a point $s_0$ and a $\delta > 0$, such that $g''(s) > 0$ on $(s_0 - \delta, s_0)$ and $g''(s) < 0$ on $(s_0, s_0+ \delta).$

We have,
$$
 g^{'}(s) = \frac{a_1 c_1}{s^3} \exp( - \frac{c_1}{2s^2} )+ \frac{a_2 c_2}{s^3} \exp(-\frac{c_2}{2s^2}).
$$
And
$$
g^{''}(s) =  \frac{a_1 c_1}{s^4} \exp( -\frac{c_1}{2s^2})\left( \frac{c_1}{s^2}- 3 \right) + \frac{a_2 c_2}{s^4} \exp( -\frac{c_2}{2s^2})\left( \frac{c_2}{s^2}- 3\right)
$$

The expression for $g^{''}(s)$ shows $g^{''}(s) > 0$ if $s < \min \{ \sqrt{c_1}, \sqrt{c_2} \}/\sqrt{3}$ and $g^{''}(s) < 0$ for $s > \max \{\sqrt{c_1},\sqrt{c_2}\}/\sqrt{3}.$

So we can find $0 < s_1 < s_2$ such that $g^{''}(s_1) > 0$ and $g^{''}(s_2) < 0$.

Define $s_0 = \sup \{ s \in [s_1,s_2] : g''(s) \geq 0 \text{ for all } s \in [s_1,s] \}.$ We have $ s_1 < s_0 < s_2$ and $g''(s_0) = 0$. We also have $g''(s) \geq 0$ on $[s_1,s_0)$. 
We also note that $g''(s)$ has a holomorphic extension to $\mathbb{C}-\{0\}$ so all zeros of $g''(s)$ in particular $s_0$ are isolated. So there is neighborhood of $(s_0 - \delta, s_0 + \delta) \subseteq [s_1,s_2]$ in which $s_0$ is the only zero of $g''(s)$. In particular $g''(s)$ does not change sign in $(s_0-\delta,s_0)$ and $(s_0,s_0+\delta)$. Since $g''(s) \geq 0$ on $(s_0-\delta,s_0)$ and it never vanishes, we must have $g''(s_0) > 0$ on $(s_0-\delta,s_0)$. Similarly we must have $g''(s) > 0$ throughout $(s_0,s_0+\delta)$ or $g''(s) < 0$ throughout $(s_0,s_0+\delta)$. $g''(s) > 0$ throughout $(s_0,s_0+\delta)$  is not possible by the definition of $s_0$ so we must have $g''(s) < 0$ throughout $(s_0,s_0+\delta)$. Thus $g''(s) > 0$ on $(s_0 - \delta,s_0)$ and $g''(s) < 0$ on $(s_0,s_0 + \delta)$ and $s_0$ is an inflection point.